# Wowza RTMP Authentication for iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift3, rtmp, wowza

I used **LFLive** kit for **rtmp** publishing, its working very well. unfortunately its not have a authentication module. how to do **rtmp** authentication for wowza in **iOS**? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i had integrate  year ago.. you need to enable from server side. But first you need to setup wowza server on your server and add the application with username & password.

> https://www.wowza.com/docs/how-to-enable-username-password-authentication-for-rtmp-and-rtsp-publishing

after that add the same username and password (set on server) in iOS application (wowza sdk' settings).

Comment: Hai Mahipal Thank you for your replay. i already setup wowza server we don't used wowza sdk we have used Lf live kit library.there is anyway to setup authentication in Lflivekit?